After death there is immortality or nothing
After death there is Immortality or Nothing
If you were to die, then what do you think would happen to you?
In best case, you go to heaven, and you live there forever in eternal bliss, but how long can you live in bliss when you have eternity. At some point in time, heaven will become a mental asylum.
On the other hand, if you go to hell, you suffer for eternity.
If you are reincarnated, then you forget everything about your this life. The memories that made you the person you are now. After reincarnation, you will be a different person. Soul might be the same, but when that person has a totally different personality, does soul really matter at that point. But in most cases, reincarnation has an end. If it has an end point, then what. Becoming one with the universe or God? But then again, will that universe and God be you? What happens to your consciousness?
If you die and your consciousness just dies as well, then what?
And if you are in a simulation, then all the previous arguments still applies that is if we our consciousness is just a computing of a complex computer, then we will most likely die with our consciousness.
If there is something else that happens to you after death, it's still immortality or nothing.
In all the scenarios, we are immortal or nothing, and none of these scenarios seems like a good ending we work hard to achieve.
In every story, there is an end to it. A goal.
Most philosophers say that death is out of our control, so don't worry about it.
But should we really ignore such a massive part of our lives? Death is something everyone will experience. But how can you explain something that's so unknown as death?
I don't want an answer that makes me comfortable about death. I know that being scared of death doesn't really make any difference in life.
I am just confused about death.
All the life experience and most of the time endure and at the end Immortality or Nothing.
PS: I am not suicidal or anything like that. I am new to philosophy and just confused about death.
Edit: I think most people misinterpreted my question. It's my bad. English is not my first language, so I could not word the question properly. I don't want to know what happens after death. It's like asking what is the meaning of life? It is a subjective answering. There is no one true answer to that.
No, What I mean is that, every versions of afterlife leads to you living forever or dying forever. Living forever is easy to explain. It's immortality (like heaven or hell etc). But death forever is like having your consciousness erased forever, your memories erased forever or if you merge with a higher, then I don't think it will be my consciousness that will be controlling that higher being. My soul or memories might survive in that higher being,  but I as an individual will be dead.
What I want a answer to is that, is there a another version of afterlife where at the end of your life you don't live forever or die forever or die as an individual forever. That is what I meant by "after death there is immortality or nothing".

It is like in Ecclesiastes where he says that a good person who worked hard and virtuously has to leave it all to someone else at death, who might be a fool. Yeah, life doesn't make sense. But it can still be enjoyed and lived well.

We have zero hard facts with which to answer this question. Different traditions give different answers. Philosophers whose background is in one tradition tend to give that tradition's answer.  I don't think we can do any better here.

Or transmigration/reincarnation. Or something we can't imagine. Or something horrible like being aware that your brain is progressively dying, which I would rather not have imagined, thank you very much. NO DATA IS NO DATA

It feels like we need a new TV category: this question can only spawn superstitious answers. I was tempted to try to keep the question open just to see how many bullshit answers we can assemble in week. But this is not a site for esoterics.

It does sound like a declaration (it's barely a question) better suited to one or more of the faith-based stacks.

The question would still be unclear. Of course any model is possible. We coud live in an afterlife for only one more year then die. We could live n years. We could come back a limited number of times. We could transform, merge, split... But humanity does not know, so what is the question really about?

My question was, Is there a concept of afterlife outside of just being alive and dead that, I wouldn't know of in any philosophy or religion doesn't matter from where. I know that my question was emotion, when look back at it, But what more did you expect from a person who was writing it at 2am not being able to sleep. I don't know how to ask  it better. If just write " concept outside of alive and dead" many people would just say "a ghost" but even as a ghost you still have your consciousness. And again I am sorry for bad grammar and wording of things I write.

@keshlam, I want to know why my question is more suited to faith-based stacks. As far as I know, most philosophers after BC were very religious and used philosophy to prove God. Where do you draw the line between philosophy and religion? Because throughout centuries both have influenced each other so much.

@tkruse I am confused as to why the site is not for esoterics. Most philosophers' ideas were/are considered esoteric. For example, the First idea of atoms was introduced in ancient Greek. Just think about the idea of atoms from the perspective of an ancient Greek person. That idea would be considered esoteric outside of philosophy. link

@Devilman: What philosophy has established is that philosophy cannot prove or disprove god, or any aspect thereof. What can be discussed is how various religions interpret their faith, but that's really a discussion of faith, perhaps informed by philosophy, rather than of philosophy. The fact that math is used in physics does not mean that a physics forum should welcome all math questions; some are better handled in a discussion focused primarily on math. Of course, that's just my opinion. But the problem is, discussion of religion eventually comes down to opinion, either received or current.

@Devilman, most things that were esoteric never made it anywhere, let alone into philosophy. So we can cherry pick only those things that became philosophy, and even drop philosophy that turned out to be garbage.

The non-dual master Nisargadatta Maharaj said:

What happens to a person after death is according to his thought/imagination.
A Christian who believes in heaven and hell will go to heaven and hell; a Hindu who believes in rebirth will have a rebirth; a Muslim who believes that he hovers around his grave till the Judgment Day will hover around his grave.

Nisardagatta then concluded with:

Since I was never born for me there is no death.

Jesus Christ indicated a similar truth in

Before Abraham was I AM

Note that its am not was so Jesus is not suggesting that he lives thousands of years, but rather that the concept of time (and therefore death) does not apply to him.

This aligns with the central non-dual teaching that birth and death can only be second hand data, never first hand experiences. I just died can never be uttered; similarly neither can I am experiencing birth. The closest we have is the everyday experience of waking in the morning and sleeping at night — processes for which no fear is experienced.
Hence — the non-dualist concludes — the fear about death and the worry of the after-death state is entirely a product of the mind's habit to imagine things.

"death can only be second hand data" - Interesting concept (and new for me).

@TheMatrixEquation-balance One could say that the whole purpose of advaita vedanta is to map borning-dying to waking-sleeping.  In the earlier stages when the mind is still driving wild, to add borning as the complementary term to dying. As the practitioner gets more adept at ' the worship of consciousness' to forget about birth-death that are just thoughts to awakening- 'asleepening' which are primary non negotiable experience

All your questions are answered in Indian Philosophy (Perennial Philosophy).
Most of these doubts will disappear when you understand some basics. You may be thinking that they are like dogmas or axioms that cannot be doubted or questioned. But fact is that those who have realized or experienced the truth never could / would question them.  Only when the truth is realized do all the questions disappear.
Truths can be classified mainly into two – Conventional Truth & Ultimate truth
And your questions are only valid when they are considered as conventional truth.
Your main question is --  “After death there is immortality or nothing”.  You just ask this: After death of what?
You are the creation, the Creator,
And the magical variety of created things,
Are You not, O God,
Even the substance of creation too.
(If you like ... you can google and find out the main text of the above translation of a prayer created for children ... which is very useful to others also.)
Modern science will someday reach this conclusion.
The ideas of hell and heaven are meant to prevent people from harming others and thus purify you. And this is often good for those who give more importance to feelings than thoughts. But this becomes  very harmful to the whole world if it is used for sending others to 'hell'.

Wiliam James helped to found the American Society for Psychical Research, with the desire of finding scientific evidence of what happens when we die. Here is a paper discussing James and his history with mediums:  https://www.aapsglobal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Schwartz-William-James-and-the-Search-for-Scientific-Evidence-of-Life-After-Death.pdf
Parapsychology continues to study the phenomena that provide relevant clues, including mediumship, reincarnation, and remote viewing (out of body travel).  Here is a link to the premier parapsychology society: https://parapsych.org/home.aspx
There is in addition an affiliated branch related to the New Age movement that explores afterlife questions in a less formal setting than a science lab.  The best of these efforts are found in a variety of books that I would recommend.  Edith Fiore's The Unquiet Dead, James Monroe's Journeys Out of Body, Michael Newton's  past life regression studies, and Joseph Fisher's The Siren Call of Hungry Ghosts are among the best of this suite of books.
Do these studies converge on a single answer?  No, but they tend to provide similar answers.  They imply that we humans can interact with a spiritual realm, that at least some of us reincarnate, and that others of us get "lost" instead.  The details of reincarnation vary between authors, as does the nature of spirit beings.

"Do these studies converge on a single answer? No, but they tend to provide similar answers" no, they don't. The similarity only exists in your personal mind, because you crave for this and you activate all your biases to get such a thing. Philosophy does not recognize any such similarity beyond what must be expected from biases.

@tkruse You are repeatedly posting your personal "wish it were so" philosophy over and over.  No, your personal wish it were so beliefs are not what "philosophy" thinks.

Then cite any interepdent source that says 'it all points to a spiritual realm with some reincarnation and stuff. Anything by anyone whose income does not depend on propagating such narratives.

@tkruse  I satisfy your arbitrary request.  Done.  Do I win a prize?  Will you stop posting your unsupported opinions now?  Or do your requests mean absolutely nothing, merely to be followed by new arbitrary bar raising in turn?
